# Android Studio Firestore RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I have a question. I want my code to display data i got in Firebase firestore in a RecyclerView but somehow it doesnt show me anything... I used to work with Realtime Database but I just cant see what i did wrong
Does anyone know what i did wrong?

Code:

```
private void readInfo() {

    LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
    manager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    manager.setReverseLayout(true);

    mNewInfo = new ArrayList<>();

    Query query = db.collection("Infos").limit(15);
    query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            mNewInfo.clear();
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot queryDocumentSnapshot : task.getResult()) {
                NewInfo newInfo = queryDocumentSnapshot.toObject(NewInfo.class);
                mNewInfo.add(newInfo);
                infoAdapter = new InfoAdapter(getContext(), mNewInfo);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(infoAdapter);
            }
            infoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

}
```

```
public class InfoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<InfoAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    Context mContext;
    private List<NewInfo> mNewInfo;

    public InfoAdapter(Context mContext, List<NewInfo> mNewInfo) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mNewInfo = mNewInfo;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public InfoAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_information, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        NewInfo newInfo = mNewInfo.get(position);

        holder.showInfo.setText(newInfo.getMessage());
        holder.title.setText(newInfo.getTitle());

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), SeeInfo.class);
                intent.putExtra("id", newInfo.getId());
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        if (newInfo.getWay().equals("1")) {
            holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.info);
        } else {
            holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.important);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView title, showInfo;
        ImageView image;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            showInfo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.infoText);
            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a notoriously inefficient interactive debugger, so you'll have to do some more of that yourself. If you run the code in a debugger and set breakpoints, does it ever reach your `onComplete` method? If you then step through it, does it go into the loop? Does `newInfo` contain the data from the database? Does it get added to `mNewInfo` correctly?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Please also add the content of your "NewInfo" class.

Comment: I actually already solved it. The problem was that i didnt return NewInfo...But thank you very much for your help